# Issue with CSS media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm having trouble with CSS media queries.

It won't recognize the line of code that I'm calling for the query.

I'm not sure what to do here, I see my CSS and it looks ok and should not be a problem, and yet...

Does anybody have this issue?

Is there something wrong in my code?

[image]

This is my CSS code:

```
@media  screen and (max-width: 600px) {

     .container {
      font-family:'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      overflow: auto;
     background-color: #fff; 
    }    
    }

    body{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: rgba(228,227,227,1);

    }

    .container{
        width: 800px;
        height: auto;
        clear: both;
        margin: 40px auto;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: #fff; 
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the link of the hosted site so that we can check ?

Comment: If your image is anything to go by, you seem to be confused that the line is in grey and not syntax-highlighted like you might expect it to be?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes. its also not working. maybe problem with code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code I think your issue is a matter of order. You're calling your media query before the non-media query style so anything you set inside that media query is being overriden, here's how it needs to be in order for your media query to override the non-media query styles.

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(228,227,227,1);
}
.container{
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    clear: both;
    margin: 40px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #fff; 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .container {
          font-family:'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          position: relative;
          overflow: auto;
          background-color: #fff; 
    }    
}
```

Comment: Well, First of all, thank you. but I'm seeing now in my CSS file that it works even without this order, but it's always good to have everything in the right order. The reason I did not saw it working in the first place was because I made the query on an element that has no effect on the site. Thank you very much.